# use some functions of move_base

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, global-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! Is there any way to use only some functions of move_base? I want to use in my node only the global costmap created with move_base and nothing else (no planners)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192179/use-some-functions-of-move_base/) by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can either create a costmap object yourself in your code or if you want the one from move_base, just start it as normal and don't call the planners. move_base won't do anything if you don't send it anything.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-09-08**:
This is correct. Check out the costmap2d_node in the costmap package.